# actualizar registros en base de datos local c#

Tags: c#, sql

tengo una base de datos local de la cuál obtengo las configuraciones para realizar unas conexiones y mostrar datos, mi idea es desde un dataGridView al seleccionar una fila pasar los valores a unos textBox y desde ahi poder modificar la base de datos. He probado lo siguiente y no me funciona, ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de actualizar los registros? Gracias.

```
    private string cadenaConexion = Properties.Settings.Default.Conexion;
    private SqlConnection CN;
    private SqlCommand CMD;
    private SqlDataReader RDR;

 // ESTO ES LO QUE ESTABA INTENTANDO PARA MODIFICARLOS DESDE UN DATAGRIDVIEW

   private void dvgAjustesContentClick(object sender, 
  DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dgv = dvgAjustes.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        tbId.Text = dgv.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        tbSala.Text = dgv.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        tbGas.Text = dgv.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        tbIP.Text = dgv.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        tbModbusDatos.Text = dgv.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        tbModbusTotal.Text = dgv.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

    }

    private void actualizarClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CN = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        string actualizar = "UPDATE DATOSconf SET SALA = " + tbSala + ", GAS = " + tbGas + ", IP = " + tbIP + ", MODBUS MEDIDA =" + tbModbusDatos + ", MODBUS TOTAL = " + tbModbusTotal + "where ID = " + tbId;




        try
        {
            CN.Open();
            CMD = new SqlCommand(actualizar, CN);
            MessageBox.Show("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO CORRECTAMENTE");
            CN.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("FALLO AL ACTUALIZAR EL REGISTRO");

        }
        }
```

Comment: Mas alla de que todo esto no parece muy necesario (para que pasarlos a un textbox?) cual seria el problema?

Comment: Te refieres a porque no actualizar los registros directamente desde la tabla del DataGridView? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En el `catch` será más util si pones algo del estilo

```
MessageBox.Show("FALLO AL ACTUALIZAR EL REGISTRO. " + ex.Message);
```

A bote pronto tienes un error al construir la setencia de sql (en la variable actualizar), todos los valores string deben estar rodeados de comilla simple y los campos cuyo nombre tenga un espacio, delimitados por corchetes (p.e. `[MODBUS TOTAL]`)

```
string actualizar = "UPDATE DATOSconf SET SALA = '" + tbSala + "', GAS = '" + tbGas + "', IP = '" + tbIP + "', [MODBUS MEDIDA] ='" + tbModbusDatos + "', [MODBUS TOTAL] = '" + tbModbusTotal + "' where ID = " + tbId;
```

Comment: SI y solo SI los campos fueran todos de tipo varchar (o lo que sea un string en esa base de datos). Si no, va a seguir tirando error.

Comment: @gbianchi, también en el caso de fecha, y también el update se producirá aunque en la sentencia pongamos comillas simples a campos que sean numéricos, .

Comment: son Int: id, modbus total y modbus datos, los demas son varchar, el problema es que no me salta excepción, lo unico que hace es arroja el messagebox de actualizado correctamente pero no se actualiza nada.

Comment: Mira el valor de `tbId`, probablemente sea un valor que no existe en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que no usas parametros

```
private void actualizarClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion)){
           CN.Open();

           string actualizar = "UPDATE DATOSconf SET SALA = @sala, GAS = @gas, IP = @ip, [MODBUS MEDIDA] = @media, [MODBUS TOTAL] = @total where ID = @id";

           SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(actualizar, CN);
           CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale", tbSala.Text);
           CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gas", tbGas.Text);
           CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", tbIP.Text);
           CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@media", tbModbusDatos.Text);
           CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", tbModbusTotal.Text);
           CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(tbId.Text));

           CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO CORRECTAMENTE");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FALLO AL ACTUALIZAR EL REGISTRO");
    }
}
```

como veras se usa el `Parameters.AddWithValue()` y debes respetar los tipos de datos, si el campo es numerico debes convertir a ese tipo de dato

Los campos que tienen espacio en su nombre deberias ponerlo entre `[]`, pero recomendaria cambies esos nombres y quites los espacios

Comment: @mourazo es CMD.ExecuteNonQuery, Leandro cometi un error supongo ya lo arreglara..

Comment: edito el ejemplo para arreglarlo